# SPF wrong IP bcc user receives message

Tags: gmail, spf, bcc

A domain is configured to allow one IP address only as the designated email sender. This is configured using an SPF entry.

When my .NET smtp client sends an email from a different IP address other than the one specified in the SPF record the message does not arrive at the recipient, as you would expect. However if I add a bcc recipient the bcc recipient does receive the email even though the IP address is not permitted to send.

Is this normal? What is the reason for this?

Comment: Without knowing the policy and the domains in question, I'd say the BCC recipient's email server doesn't do SPF validation at all, or only for this email (e.g. sender is whitelisted).